# Bootstrap dl-horizontal - How to force last character to show

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to truncate text in my `dl` elements with "..."

Example:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
   <dt>Birth Date:</dt>
```

What it should look like:

Birth Da...

And I try to obtain:

Birth D...:

I can fix it with:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
   <dt>Birth Date:</dt><trong>:</strong>
```

But it isn't a good idea to keep the right alignment, because in HTML view

First name:
Your Last name:
           Birth Da...:

":" isn't aligned right

CSS code:

```
  .dl-horizontal dt {
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    clear: left;
    text-align: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add your css ? 
Could you try white-space : normal ?

Comment: Is ccs boostrap by default.

White space normal make no "..." appears

Comment: Post your jsfiddle first and we check :)

Answer (score 0):

Keep an un-packed version of bootstrap.css around of the latest you're using, then go find in the CSS and change it:

**This will give you more space, can't be precise as to the characters:**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dl-horizontal dt {
    width: 180px;

  }
  .dl-horizontal dd {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
}
```

This will give you more space. You always put changes to Bootstrap's css after theirs.

Comment: Thanks but I can not change the style due to a design decision. I need only add ":"

Answer (score 0):

you can comment out white-space: nowrap; from .dl-horizontal dt block if you want to wrap content in all the dt

if you want to wrap content for a single dt then add inline style='white-space: normal;' to that specific dt